# Changing ports when configuring Nifi; Why do I get SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT on HTTPS port 9443?

Tags: apache-nifi

I've recently attempted to install Apache Nifi 1.13.2 on a Ubuntu 20.04. (Java version: OpenJDK 11.) The default nifi.properties web properties section allows it to run normally using HTTP on port 8080, but it fails if I change it to any other port.

For an example using HTTP, it refuses connections if I change `nifi.web.http.port` to 9300 and attempt to connect to localhost:9300/nifi. And if I instead (presumably in concordance with current best-practices) change `nifi.web.https.port` to 9443, `nifi.web.https.host` to 127.0.0.1, and make the relevant changes to `nifi.remote.input.secure` (changing it to true) and `nifi.remote.input.http.enabled` (changing it to false), attempting to browse to `https://localhost:9443/nifi` yields a SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT error.

(I do not have both the `nifi.web.http.host/port` and `nifi.web.https.host/port` settings enabled at the same time; that tends to throw IllegalStateExceptions.)

Can anyone point to me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

if `nifi.remote.input.secure` is enabled `https` port gets priority over `http` port.
however you also need certificates to have secure instance for which you can use `nifi toolkit` to generate.

[bryan's post](https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/08/17/apache-nifi-1-0-0-authorization-and-multi-tenancy) may help you, a little old but still valid. you may read only certificates section (it covers both security and cluster)